# Math/programming: How to make an object go through a path made from a line

Tags: vb6, 2d, line, collision

Now I am doing this in VB6 but I don't think it matters what I do it in, does it? I believe it has to do with math.

Here is the problem, have a look at this picture

[image]

As you can see in this image,  there is a black line and a grey circle. I want the circle to move from the bottom left to the bottom right, but I also want it to stay along the path of the line so it reaches our second picture like this:

[image]

Now how can I accomplish this? Again, using VB6.

Comment: Please don't post the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073590/vb6-how-to-use-a-line-as-a-path) twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I don't know VBA6 but, since you said:

> I don't think it matters what I do it in

I will give a generic solution that involves you having the center of the circles coordinates, and the lines endpoints.

This line can be treated as a vector:

```
 (line.x2-line.x1, line.y2-line.y1)
```

You don't need to write this in your program or anything just saying it is a vector.

What you do need to is get the magnitude of the vector and assign it to a variable:

```
unitSize = sqrt((line.x2-line.x1)^2 + (line.y2-line.y1)^2)
```

Now make it into unit vector components and get the separate components:

```
unitX = (line.x2-line.x1)/unitSize
unitY = (line.y2-line.y1)/unitSize
```

Now how ever you update the circle:

```
do {
    circle.x = circle.x + unitX * incrementSize //incrementSize scales how big the movement is assign it to whatever you seem fit.
    circle.y = circle.y + unitY * incrementSize
until (circle.x >= line.x2) //Or <= line.x2 depends which way you are going.
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Okay I have implemented what you have told me, and I understand it. It works for positve line angles but not the other way around, it gives me an error when I identify unitSize when it is a negative line. what could be the solution?

Comment: @Qasim: I made a mistake in my magnitude calculation... Now it should work all the time. I forgot to square the thing. Not, only is that wrong, but you can get - numbers. sqrt and neg numbers = :(

Comment: Here is the line of the error: `unitSize = Sqr((ShotLine(t).X2 - ShotLine(t).X1) + (ShotLine(t).Y2 - ShotLine(t).Y1))` It says invalid call or procedure, the equation cant be completed? This happens whenever the line angle is opposite, what could be the problem?

Comment: @Qasim: `unitSize = Sqr((ShotLine(t).X2 - ShotLine(t).X1)^2 + (ShotLine(t).Y2 - ShotLine(t).Y1)^2)`

Comment: @ anon: Should this code replace the other, or only replace when the line is in the opposite direction?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4855/discussion-between-qasim-and-anon)

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways of accomplishing this I think, but here's the first that comes to my mind.  It makes some assumptions... like that your line goes in a positive direction and it starts at 0,0.  If either of these things aren't true then you've got more code to write to adjust for that.

=================================================

```
    Psuedocode:
    'To track current coordinates of the center of the circle
    dim x as float, y as float
    x = 0: y = 0

    'Coordinates for the line
    dim x1 as float, y1 as float, x2 as float, y2 as float
    x1=0: y1=0: x2=50: y2=75

    'How much we're going to move the circle at a time
    dim xStep as float, yStep as float, stepSize as float
    stepSize = 100
    xStep = x2 / stepSize
    yStep = y2 / stepSize

    Do
       'Draw circle here with x, y for coordinates
       x = x + xStep
       y = y + yStep
    Loop Until xStep > x2
```